# Is changing inherited variable name is still considred as override?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, operator-overloading, overriding

As ask above I have a function with one input parameter in base class.

1. Does overriding it in derived class but with change of the variable name still considered as **override** and not as **overload**?
   I know it is the case for languages such as Java, but what about php?

   `abstract public foo($a);` --> class A1
   `public foo($b){}`        --> class B1  (B1 extends A1)
2. Same questions but with little different case:
   `abstract public foo (Vehicle $car)`  --> class A2
   `public foo (Mercedes $myCar)`       --> class B2  (B2 extends A2) AND (class Mercedes extends class vehicle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Won't produce any errors, it works just fine. But there won't be two different foo methods, just one

   abstract class A {
       abstract public function foo($a);
   }

   class B extends A {
       public function foo($b) {}
   }
2. Will produce this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of B::foo() must be compatible with
>   A::foo(Vehicle $a) in /home/test.php on line 11

```
class Vehicle {}
class Car extends Vehicle {}

abstract class A {
    abstract public function foo(Vehicle $a);
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo(Car $b) {}
}
```

There's no overloading in PHP, just overriding